# Is it recommended to initialize firebase authentication on a client action?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Before my question, our front end stack is running React + Redux with firebase. As part of our performance initiative, I'm tasked on figuring out if we can load firebase on action (maybe it's not recommended?).

NOTE: I am able to initialize firebase for authenticated users (looked in indexedDB to see if firebase key exists then we import the firebase scripts to initialize).

The problem I'm having currently, is to initialize firebase on a client action (i.e. user clicks on a button to sign in, initialize firebase, and open up form to begin sign in process). We have several actions, but currently our implementation initializes firebase and uses the "onAuthStateChanged" method to set our redux store to see whether user is authenticated or not (with this we determine what the user sees and what the user can do).

Has anyone ever encountered this? Is it recommended? Everything I looked into firebase is initialized on page load (which works great!) But as part of increasing our page performance on "non-authenticated" users will be some gains, is it worth the gains for the level of effort?

Any feedback, or guidance will be greatly appreciated!

I tried creating a high order component(React connecting to redux) to pass in the redux actions to the initialization firebase utils (that we created), that would then calls `onAuthStateChanged`(with the callback to the redux actions) after we initialize firebase.

```
...
    firebaseInitialize: async () => {
      await onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          props.signIn(user.isAnonymous); // redux action
        } else {
          setModelValue('data', UserProfileModel, {});
          props.signOut(); // redux action
        }
      }); // this is a wrapper method where we initialize firebase and called the firebase's "onAuthStateChanged" method

      return Promise.resolve();
    },
...
```

```
  handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {
      validate,
      toggleSignUpModal,
      toggleSignInModal,
      fields,
      firebaseInitialize,
      createAnonymousIdmProfile,
      validateEmailAsync,
      pageName,
      venomVersion,
      userEmail,
      toggleSpinner,
      setSubmittedState,
    } = this.props;

    toggleSpinner();
    const isValid = validate();
    const emailAsyncValidation = await validateEmailAsync(pageName, venomVersion);

    if (isValid && emailAsyncValidation.isEmailValid) {
      const emailValue = userEmail || fields.email.value();
      await firebaseInitialize(); // trying to initialize firebase here before continuing with other firebase methods being called.
      const signInMethods = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(emailValue);
      const userHasAccount = signInMethods.length;
      const toggleModal = userHasAccount ? toggleSignInModal : toggleSignUpModal;
      setSubmittedState(true);
      try {
        if (!userHasAccount && !userEmail) {
          await signInAnonymously(CREATIVE_ID, { subaction_name: TrackingConstant.SUCCESS_EMAIL_ONLY_SIGN_UP });
          await createAnonymousIdmProfile({ identifiers: { email: [emailValue] }, isAnonymous: true });
        }
        toggleModal({ email: emailValue });
        toggleSpinner();
      } catch (e) {
        logger('warn', 'profile is not saved to a storage properly', e);
      }
    } else {
      toggleSpinner();
    }
  };
...
```

Comment: Why not share `onAuthStateChanged` logic. It is not clear what do you mean by initialization, do you write Firebase scripts to html document or just do `initializeApp`? BTW there is a reference in docs which does not indicate that you need to run `initializeApp` on load https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#multiple-projects

Comment: We just do `initializeApp`